# How do you make JSSOR accessible?

Tags: accessibility, jssor, jaws-screen-reader

JSSOR can pass HTML validation as noted http://www.jssor.com/development/pass-html-validation.html

It provides key access but does it support full accessibility - for example, access with a screen reader?

Comment: Not sure, please try.

Comment: Ok, seems that most can be dealt with in the template:  tabindex, alt text. Additional styling can be added to contrast for selected item. Keyboard navigation support via keys after tabbing into the slider. 

This covers the basic use-cases.  Still need further validation using screen readers (such as JAWS) to see if the keyboard access interferes with the buffers.